# Changing player between bot and human in python tic tac toe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

As a noob I'm creating Tic Tac Toe on Python (Jupyter Notebook used). Granted my coding looks almost childish compared to some of the more advanced examples i've seen, but I am still learning the various built-in functions and becoming more efficient, so I apologize for that. The issue regards the changing of human player ('X') and bot ('O') after 2nd move of human.Below is my code and the final output. Could anyone possibly advise as to why the bots choices stop reflecting after round 1?

```
winner = False
moves = 0

 while winner == False or moves < 10:    
    player_choice(moves)
    print (f'(The current player is {moves})')
    final_output()
    if result_check() == True:
        winner == True
        break
    if game_on() == False:
        break
    moves += 1
    
    if winner == True:
        print(f'(We have a winner, player {curr_player})')
        print(final_output())
    else: print("Game has been ended by User...goodbye")
```

The function I used to alternate the moves between bot and human was as follows:

```
def player_choice(mover):

    placed = ''
    placed_2 = ''
    filled_cells = []
    
    if mover %2 !=0:
        while placed_2 == '':
            bot_choice = random.randint(0,8)
            print(f'(the bots choice was {bot_choice})')
            if bot_choice not in filled_cells:
                test[bot_choice] = 'O'
                placed_2 == "done"
                filled_cells.append(bot_choice)
                return True
   
    elif mover%2 == 0':
        while placed == '':
            p_choice = int(input('Please select cell from 1-9 : '))-1
            if test[p_choice] not in filled_cells:
                test[p_choice] = 'X'
                filled_cells.append(p_choice)
                placed == 'done'
                return True
            elif test[p_choice] in filled_cells:
                print('Sorry, that cell has been chosen, please select another')
```

My result looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CR! This site is for working code only. Please see [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and take the [tour].